# MongoDB - How to construct a find with input array like this

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm a beginner MongoDB developer and I'm having trouble constructing this `.find()` statement.

Problem:

- I have a list of Bus Stop Codes and I am looking to query the database for detailed information on these Bus Stops for a Bus Route App API

Example:

- I have an array of Bus Stop Codes `[1, 4, 5, 3, 1]`. I need to return an array of objects from the bus stop that matches these Bus Stop Codes.

The end product has to be:

1. In the same order as the order in the array
2. Include duplicates (the array starts and ends at the same bus stop, and I must retrieve both the start and the end as two separate bus stops in the resulting object).

So far, I have tried

```
.find( StopCode: {$in: [1, 4, 5, 3, 1]})
```

But I

1. Receive results with the StopCodes in ascending order, and not the order of the array
2. Do not receive the start and end stops as separate bus stop objects.

Anyone have any clue how to do this? I've been stuck on it for awhile and would appreciate some help :)

Comment: What are your schema details

Comment: Perhaps try using `$map`.  This should preserve order and redundancy is irrelevant.  If you provide some sample documents and a desired output (edit your question), I'm confident someone could give you a working query.

Comment: add your schemas to your question

Comment: Must the query be `find`, or is `aggregate` also acceptable?